# Why does the Oxidizing agent have to be higher than Reducing agent for a redox reaction to spontaneously occur?

Tags: electrochemistry

On the Standard Reduction Potentials of Half-Cells table, why does the Oxidizing agent have to be higher than Reducing agent for a redox reaction to spontaneously occur?

Comment: I thought that the only requirement was: if $E^{\circ}$ is positive = the redox is spontaneous. I thought that it did not matter which one is more positive.

Comment: You're right. It has to be positive and I get that. However, that's the mathematical explanation. But how can you explain it scientifically?

Comment: Need some clarification here based on your comment. Are you interested in why a positive cell potential means a negative deltaG or are you interested in why a negative deltaG means spontaneous reaction?

Comment: The sign convention may be considered to be  'back to front' since $\Delta G=-nF\Delta E$ with  $\Delta E$ as the difference in standard redox potentials for the reaction. $\Delta G$ is negative for a spontaneous reaction. Oxidising agents have more positive redox $E^0$ in tables of redox potentials than reducing agents do. It is the difference in redox that determines if a reaction is spontaneous.  'Scientifically'  a *reducing agent* is an electron donor and so an *oxidising agent* is an electron acceptor.